pyinstaller won't package python-docx
Goal
I want to package a simple python app (let's call it wordy), that creates a basic word document using the python-docx libary, into a single .exe file.
setup
PyCharm project with poetry as the interpreter. python-docx installed after selecting is in Settings > Project > Python Intepreter.
using pip show python-docx, I found docx here:
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\wordy-nOisIA6h-py3.10\Lib\site-packages\docx

problem
The program works file when ran in PyCharm.
But the executable I created in the /dist folder, throws an error when ran from the command line:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
what I tried
The below commands were run from the PyCharm terminal from within the virtualenv
(docxpoc-nOisIA6h-py3.10) PS C:\wordy> 

pyinstaller --onefile main.py --name "wordy1.exe"
pyinstaller --onefile main.py --name "wordy2.exe" --hidden-import docx
pyinstaller --onefile main.py --name "wordy3.exe" --additional-hooks-dir myhooks.py
pyinstaller --onefile main.py --name "wordy4.exe" --collect-data "docx" 


pyi-makespec --onefile main.py
pyinstaller .\main.spec

Only when I use the .spec file do I get something other than the above error msg. I get:
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "wordy.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI112442\docx\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from docx.image.bmp import Bmp
  File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI112442\docx\image.py", line 3, in <module>
    from __future__ import annotations
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__future__'

I don't see "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI112442 in this location, btw.```
The only change I made to the generated spec file was to insert a tuple in the datas=[] line.
datas=[("C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/pypoetry/Cache/virtualenvs/wordy-nOisIA6h-py3.10/Lib/site-packages/docx/*.*", "docx")]

I also tried hiddenimports=["docx"] but ended up with the original error msg.

The MEI folder is generated at runtime by pyinstaller.
Your problem is probably with the "future" import in the code if you are using python 3.

thanks for your input! I am using python 3 but 'future' was not added by me, must be called by python-docx.
